# New to pygame. This "for i in range" doesn't work

Tags: python

```
from random import randint
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
ekraan = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])
valge = [255, 255, 255]
ekraan.fill(valge)
pygame.display.set_caption("Ülesanne 6")
pygame.display.flip()


värv1 = randint(0, 255)
värv2 = randint(0, 255)
värv3 = randint(0, 255)
asukoht_x = randint(0, 800)
asukoht_y = randint(0, 600)
suurus = randint(5, 100)

i = 1
for i in range(100):
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, (värv1, värv2, värv3), [asukoht_x, asukoht_y], suurus, 0) 
    pygame.display.flip()
    i = i + 1



running = True
while running:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```

I'm trying to get the program to draw 100 circles that are each in a random colour, random X,Y coordinates and random size. I'm using for i in range(100) but it doesn't work. The program only draws 1 circle that has everything random.

Comment: Aren't you just drawing 100 circles in the same place with this code?  You need to re randomize it in every loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are drawing 100 circles, you're just drawing all of them in the same exact location.

```
from random import randint
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
ekraan = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])
valge = [255, 255, 255]
ekraan.fill(valge)
pygame.display.set_caption("Ülesanne 6")
pygame.display.flip()

i = 1
for i in range(100):
    # randomize colors for each circle; not just once
    värv1 = randint(0, 255)
    värv2 = randint(0, 255)
    värv3 = randint(0, 255)

    # and randomize the position and size of the circles as well
    asukoht_x = randint(0, 800)
    asukoht_y = randint(0, 600)
    suurus = randint(5, 100)

    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, (värv1, värv2, värv3), [asukoht_x, asukoht_y], suurus, 0) 
    pygame.display.flip()
    i = i + 1



running = True
while running:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```